# How to fix "Method not allowed" error in Python Flask app

Tags: python, sqlite, flask

I have a defined route in my Python Flask app(which worked fine).

```
@app.route('/insertpage', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        companyname = request.form['companyname']
        username = request.form['username']
        userpass = request.form['password']
        new_company= Grocery(companyname=companyname,
                            username=username, userpass=userpass)
        try:
            db.session.add(new_company)
            db.session.commit()
            return render_template('index.html', data=Todos.query.all())
        except:
            return "The problem occurred while adding a new company...."

    else:
        groceries = Grocery.query.order_by(Grocery.created_at).all()
        return render_template('index.html', groceries=groceries)
```

And I am collecting information in my `HTML` page:

```
 <form action="/" method="POST">
    <div class="form-row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
        <label for="newStuff" class="sr-only">New company:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="companyname" id="newStuff" placeholder="Enter name of new company">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
        <label for="newStuff" class="sr-only">New username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" id="newStuff" placeholder="Enter username...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
        <label for="newStuff" class="sr-only">New password:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="password" id="newStuff" placeholder="Enter password...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 my-1">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Add</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

After a couple of successful `CRUD` operations, I am facing the following error(even if I defined `'POST'` and `'GET'` in my def).

```
Method Not Allowed
The method is not allowed for the requested URL.
```

Comment: I am guessing the "/" route does not support POST method, maybe the form's `action` should be "/insertpage" and not "/" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `action` attribute of your HTML form needs to match the name of your Flask route.

Your page is sending a POST to url '/' , so it isn't hitting your route, which is for the path '/insertpage'

You should change it to `<form action="/insertpage" method="POST">`